How do I use the MS Graph API to change the auto reply settings on a group mailbox?
I want to use the MS Graph API to set the auto reply configuration for an Office 365 group (groupType='Unified').
I am able to do this for users, but I have not been able to do it for groups.
Here is the method I have tried:
$payload = "
    {
        '@odata.context': https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`$metadata#Me/mailboxSettings',
        'automaticRepliesSetting': {
            'status':               'scheduled',
            'externalAudience':     'all',
            'scheduledStartDateTime': {
                'dateTime':         '2024-09-12 09:00:00',
                'timeZone':         'UTC'
            },
            'scheduledEndDateTime': {
                'dateTime':         '2024-09-12 22:00:00',
                'timeZone':         'UTC'
            },
            'internalReplyMessage': 'message goes here',
            'externalReplyMessage': 'message goes here'
        }
    }"

Invoke-MGGraphRequest `
  -uri    "/groups/<GROUP_ID>/mailboxSettings" `
  -method 'PATCH' `
  -body   $payload

This is the response I receive:
Invoke-MgGraphRequest: PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/groups/<GROUP_ID>/mailboxSettings
HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
request-id: <REQUEST_ID>
client-request-id: <CLIENT_REQUEST_ID>
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Australia Southeast","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"ML1PEPF0000E51D"}}
Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2024 03:09:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip

{"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Invalid version: groups","innerError":{"date":"2024-09-12T03:09:24","request-id":<REQUEST_ID>,"client-request-id":<CLIENT_REQUEST_ID>}}}

Is it possible to do this?

There is no Graph endpoint for this afaik. You will need to target an older API like the one Exchange Online uses or the cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration?view=exchange-ps

Hi, Have you tried this documentation?

There doesn't seem to be a Graph endpoint for updating an O365 Shared Mailbox automatic replies settings thus far.
The existing Create settings and Update groupSetting endpoints have no indication that automatic replies is supported based on the existing groupSettingTemplates.
The alternative can be to use Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration or the API used behind the scenes.
$setMailboxAutoReplyConfigurationSplat = @{
    Identity         = 'theMailboxGroup@theTenant.com'
    AutoReplyState   = 'Scheduled'
    ExternalAudience = 'All'
    StartTime        = '2024-09-12 09:00:00'
    EndTime          = '2024-09-12 22:00:00'
    InternalMessage  = 'message goes here'
    ExternalMessage  = 'message goes here'
}

Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration @setMailboxAutoReplyConfigurationSplat


Thanks Santiago. This is a bit annoying because I have already set up a script to manage auto replies for users using MS Graph. The method you have described does seem to work, just would have been nice to do it all via Graph.

@BenjaminSelby I see, out of curiosity, what does happen if you use the users endpoint with the group: Invoke-MgGraphRequest PATCH 'v1.0/users/theGroupMailbox@theTenant.com/mailboxSettings' -Body $payload also in the payload you can remove the '@odata.context' line
